# Transpose a single column in DF

Tags: python, pandas

The table I have

```
{'name': {0: 'Result 1',
  1: 'Result 2',
  2: 'Result 1',
  3: 'Result 2'},
 'value': {0: '255.00', 1: '260.00', 2: '255.00', 3: '260.00'},
 'Result 3': {0: 325, 1: 325, 2: 285, 3: 285},
 'batchnumber': {0: '59530', 1: '59530', 2: '59534', 3: '59534'}}
```

The transpose I want to do is single column transpose

| index | name | value | batchnumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Result 1 | 255.00 | 59534 |
| 1 | Result 2 | 260.00 | 59534 |
| 2 | Result 3 | 285.00 | 59534 |
| 3 | Result 1 | 255.00 | 59530 |
| 4 | Result 2 | 260.00 | 59530 |
| 5 | Result 3 | 325.00 | 59530 |

I tried pivot

```
df.pivot(index='Result 3', columns='name', values='batchnumber')
df = df.transpose()
```

Comment: First this is called `reshaping` and not `transposing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot_wider then melt. In this case, you get the same results but rather unmatched rows

```
df.pivot(['batchnumber', 'Result 3'],'name', 'value').reset_index().melt('batchnumber')

   batchnumber      name  value
0        59530  Result 3  325.0
1        59534  Result 3  285.0
2        59530  Result 1  255.0
3        59534  Result 1  255.0
4        59530  Result 2  260.0
5        59534  Result 2  260.0
```

You could sort before you melt:

```
(df.pivot(['batchnumber', 'Result 3'],'name', 'value')
   .reset_index()
   .sort_index(axis=1)
   .melt('batchnumber'))

   batchnumber      name  value
0        59530  Result 1  255.0
1        59534  Result 1  255.0
2        59530  Result 2  260.0
3        59534  Result 2  260.0
4        59530  Result 3  325.0
5        59534  Result 3  285.0
```

Comment: I dont know what is happening at your end but i am getting this error "ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies 2."

Comment: @Puzzlemaster are you working on the same data as the one posted?

Comment: yes. there are some changes to make question clear. but not much. I added the original df to the answer and what is your pandas version?

Comment: @Puzzlemaster add the data. Not the image ie `df.to_dict()` share that

Comment: @Puzzlemaster your data and image are different! You shared 2 different data. Try my solution on the data you wrote previously and not on the one in the image. This code should definitely work

Comment: can you do the same for the one on the image or u want separate thread?

Comment: @Puzzlemaster Consider sharing the data as `df.to_dict()` not as an image. ie run `df.to_dict()` copy the output and paste it into your question

Comment: already did in ?

Comment: @Puzzlemaster the code I gave runs on the data you provided with no error. Try clearing your environment and run this code on your df

Comment: I guess my pandas version had some kind of problem. Thanks